# Duplicate code refactoring in Java with patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, dropwizard

This is more about Java than Dropwizard; but I have two resources in Dropwizard:  `CustomerResource` and `ApiResource`.

In `CustomerResource` there is a `createCustomer` method which basically creates a new customer. The `ApiResource` will also create a new customer when a third party invokes a method inside of it, so this got me thinking about duplicate code and the best way to resolve it. I have a few approaches in mind; but first here are the classes for better clarity.

```
@Path("/internal")        
public class CustomerResource{
    private DBDao dbDao;
    private AnotherAPI api;

    //constructor for DI

    public Response Create(@internalAuth CustomerPojo customerPojo) {
        //logic to validate customerpojo
        //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
        //some other validation logic
        //finally user creation/saving to DB
        Return response.ok(200).build();
    }
}

@Path("/external")
public class ApiResource{
    private DBDao dbDao;
    private AnotherAPI api;

    //constructor for DI

    public Response Create(@ExternalAuth PartialCustomerPojo partialCustomerPojo) {
        //logic to validate PartialCustomerpojo
        //supplement partialCustomerPojo
        //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
        //some other validation logic
        //finally user creation/saving to DB
        Return response.ok(200).build();
    }
}
```

So two main differences are how the endpoint is called (authentication) and the payload provided.

The way I thought about removing duplicate code is to create a new concrete class that takes commonality from both resources and each of them instantiates a new class like this.

```
public class CommonClass{
    private DBDao dbDao;
    private AnotherAPI api;

    //constructor for DI

    public boolean Create (CommonPojo commonPojo) {
        //logic to validate customerPojo
        //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
        //some other validation logic
        //finally user creation/saving to DB
        Return response.ok(200).build();
    }
}
```

And now inside `CustomerResource` and `ApiResource` I simply do this.

```
CommonClass commonClass = new CommonClass(dbDao, api);
//create a new instance customerPojo or CommonPojo and call 

commonClass.create(customerPojo);
```

Does this sound like a good strategy? Are there other concerns beyond duplication?  These two resource methods can't be inside the same class either. Any best practice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think inheritance not the best solution. 
Also I think that composition is much better. This can help you to use common code and easy to change it in other places where you need to change functionality.

Also it allows you to test all classes more easy.

For example:

```
class CommonPojo {}
class CustomerPojo extends CommonPojo {}
class PartialCustomerPojo extends CommonPojo {}

interface IResourceValid {
    boolean isResourceValid(CommonPojo pojo);
}

class CustomerPojoValidator implements IResourceValid {
    @Override
    public boolean isResourceValid(CommonPojo pojo) {
        //your validation for customer
        return false;
    }
}

class PartialCustomerPojoValidator implements IResourceValid {
    @Override
    public boolean isResourceValid(CommonPojo pojo) {
        //your validation for partial customer
        return true;
    }
}

class CommonResource{
    private DBDao dbDao;
    private AnotherAPI api;
    private IResourceValid validator;

    public IResourceValid getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }

    //constructor for DI

    public Response Create(CommonPojo commonPojo) {
        //logic to validate customerpojo
        //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
        //some other validation logic
        //finally user creation/saving to DB
        validator.isResourceValid(commonPojo);
        return response.ok(200).build();
    }
}

//@Path("/internal")
class CustomerResource{
    private CommonResource resource;

    //constructor for DI

    public Response Create(CustomerPojo CustomerPojo) {
        return resource.Create(CustomerPojo);
    }
}

//@Path("/external")
class ApiResource{
    private CommonResource resource;

    //constructor for DI

    public Response Create(PartialCustomerPojo partialCustomerPojo) {
        return resource.Create(partialCustomerPojo);
    }
}

DBDao dao = new DBDao();
AnotherAPI api = new AnotherAPI();

CommonResource castomerCreator = new CommonResource(new CustomerPojoValidator(), dao, api);
CommonResource apiCreator = new CommonResource(new PartialCustomerPojoValidator(), dao, api);

CustomerResource customerResource = new CustomerResource(castomerCreator);
ApiResource apiResource = new ApiResource(apiCreator);

customerResource.Create(somePojo);
apiResource.Create(someAnotherPojo);
```

Comment: with inheritance each method needs to provide their own implementation hence can't reduce duplicate code unless you opt for a default method in java 1.8 as suggested in the answer earlier. Agree with the composition approach and great point about testing. Thank you for the detailed answer and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options and it all depends on what strategy you use. I prefer to use abstract class and make non abstract methods in it. When you extend the abstract class you choose which method you want to use.
In your scenario it should look something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractResource {

    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerService(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    public Response create(CustomerPojo customer) {
        return customerService.createCustomerPojo(customer);
    }

    public Response create(PartialCustomerPojo customer) {
        return customerService.createPartialCustomerPojo(customer);
    }

}
```

The `CustomerResource` `@Override` only the method that needs:

```
@Path("/internal")
@Component
public class CustomerResource extends AbstractResource {

    @POST
    @Override
    public Response create(PartialCustomerPojo customer) {
        return super.create(customer);
    }

}
```

Same for the `ApiResource`

```
@Path("/external")
@Component
public class ApiResource extends AbstractResource {

    @POST
    @Override
    public Response create(CustomerPojo customer) {
        return super.create(customer);
    }

}
```

Everything goes in onle place - `CustomerService`, where you do your logic.

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherAPI api;

    @Autowired
    private DBDao dao;

    public Response createCustomerPojo(CustomerPojo customer) {
        //logic to validate customerpojo
        //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
        //some other validation logic
        //finally user creation/saving to DB
    }

    public Response createPartialCustomerPojo(PartialCustomerPojo customer) {
        //logic to validate PartialCustomerpojo
        //supplement partialCustomerPojo
        //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
        //some other validation logic
        //finally user creation/saving to DB
    }
}
```

If you want to minimize the duplication you have to use an interface and implement in in each class:

```
public class CustomerPojo implements PojoInterface {
}
public class PartialCustomerPojo implements PojoInterface {
}
```

Now you can have only one abstract method:

```
public abstract class AbstractResource {

    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerService(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    public abstract Response create(PojoInterface customer);

}
```

And then in 'the one place' you need to check each instance of the parameters:

```
public Response create(PojoInterface customer) {
        if (customer instanceof CustomerPojo){
            //logic to validate customerpojo
            //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
            //some other validation logic
            //finally user creation/saving to DB
        }else if (customer instanceof PartialCustomerPojo){
            //logic to validate PartialCustomerpojo
            //supplement partialCustomerPojo
            //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
            //some other validation logic
            //finally user creation/saving to DB
        }
    }
```

Edit: Sorry for the long post...

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed explanation. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by both of the following ways

1. Create an Interface and then implement on both of the target classes so they both can provide their local implementation
2. Use abstract class and then extend it.

Interface does not save you from coding but keeps things inline where abstract classes do not enforce anything so both have weaknesses. You can implement multiple interfaces but can only extend one class. Keeping that in mind I lean towards interfaces more

Since Java 8. Java supports default method using interface, which is from my opinion is the best way to go. You can provide default implementation in default method and user can override the method if they wish to. This will give you best of both Interface and Abstract class.

```
public interface CommonCode {

    default public boolean create(CommonPojo commonPojo) {
        //logic to validate customerPojo
        //logic to ensure user isn't a duplicate
        //some other validation logic
        //finally user creation/saving to DB
        Return response.ok(200).build();
    }
}

@Path("/internal")        
public class CustomerResource  implements CommonCode {
    private DBDao dbDao;
    private AnotherAPI api;

    //constructor for DI
    create(CommonPojo)
}

@Path("/external")
public class ApiResource implements CommonCode {
    private DBDao dbDao;
    private AnotherAPI api;

    //constructor for DI
    create(CommonPojo)
}
```

Comment: using interface with a default method seems like the best of both worlds. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @RethinkStrategy glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface and have both classes implement it. Add an abstract base class call between the interface and the subclasses and refactor any common code into it.

Comment: thanks. a bit confused though. can u show me a skeleton?

Comment: you are using delegation, i was suggesting using inheritance.

Comment: You should probably not be returning HTTP specific codes/objects from `CommonClass`. You should return a creation response object, or throw an exception. Then the `*Resource` classes should be responsible for interpreting the response from `CommonClass` and transforming it into the correct HTTP response

Comment: @DanielScott agreed. Good call. I don't do that usually. Wasn't thinking straight typing up the question.